# evince running remotely critical error

Tags: ssh, pdf, evince

I logged into a remote server using the -X option in the ssh command.
After trying to open a pdf file with evince i get the following error:

> ** (evince:4568): CRITICAL **: ev_bookmarks_get_bookmarks: assertion 'EV_IS_BOOKMARKS (bookmarks)' failed

The funny thing is that the pdf is visible and file open correctly.
Any idea what might be causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Does it happen when you open the same pdf locally from terminal? There can be bug in evince or it can be just bad PDF ...

Not all the critical gtk errors are actually critical.

Comment: No Error happens if I open the pdf locally, so the PDF is just fine. Is there some other pdf viewer you would suggest instead?